# How to retrieve access_token from Azure Active Directory (AAD) Web API

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, vue.js, azure-active-directory

I am building a web app with the following properties:

- The Front-end is based on VueJS
- The Back-end framework is still not confirmed but it will be a RESTFul API
- The users for the app will be authenticated by Azure Active Directory (AAD)

Here's what I have done so far:

I have set up a Web App/API in my AAD. Along with that following the guidelines [here](https://github.com/matt-ankerson/vue-adal), I have completely secured my VueJS app and now I need to be logged in into my AAD in order to be able to use the app.

The problem now is that, the front-end is secured. But what about the backend? I am trying to get an **access_token** from the AAD which I can then use as an authorization header with every request to my backend later on.

Here is what I get from my AAD when I sign in using the AuthenticationContext from the **adal** library.

[image: ADAL return]

As you can see I am getting an **id_token** and when I use the **acquireToken** function of **adal** I get an **id_token** again.

Is there anything I am doing wrong here? Do I need to create another Web App/API on Azure?

How do I go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: This sample might help you: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi

Answer (score 2):

According to official documentation and this might be your case.

"The OAuth 2.0 implicit flow in Azure AD is designed to return an ID token when the resource for which the token is being requested is the same as the client application. In other words, when the JS client uses ADAL JS to request a token for its own backend web API registered with same App ID as the client, an ID token is returned and cached by the library. Note that in this case the resource should be set to the App ID of the client (App ID URI will not work). This ID token can then be used as a bearer token in the calls to your application's backend API."

You can find more about this here!

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/wiki/Acquire-tokens

Comment: Though you really shouldn't use id tokens for authorization. That's why I usually define a separate app for the API and request for an access token to it.

Comment: So in my case I have an, on azure, an API that is my frontend Vue JS, and also an API that is my backend. 

From my frontend API, I run the acquireToken for the backed API as resource to get an access token for it. So then I use that to send as bearer + token requests to the backend with my frontend as the 'audience' during verification?

Comment: that's right.  Try passing token as is to the back end and hopefully it should work.